# SQL - find row with closest date but different column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm new to SQL and i would need an help.

I have a TAB and I need to find for any item  B in the TAB the item  A with the closest date. In this case the A with 02.09.2021 04:25:30

| Date. | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 07.09.2021 05:02:05 | A |
| 06.09.2021 05:01:02 | A |
| 05.09.2021 05:00:02 | A |
| 04.09.2021 04:59:01 | A |
| 03.09.2021 04:58:03 | A |
| 02.09.2021 04:56:55 | A |
| 02.09.2021 04:33:56 | B |
| 02.09.2021 04:25:30 | A |

Comment: What is the database that you are using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(DATE,ITEM)AS
(
    SELECT '20210907 05:02:05' ,    'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT   '20210906 05:01:02' ,  'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT   '20210905 05:00:02' ,  'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT'20210904 04:59:01' , 'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT'20210903 04:58:03' , 'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT'20210902 04:56:55' , 'A'UNION ALL
    SELECT'20210902 04:33:56' , 'B'UNION ALL
    SELECT'20210902 04:25:30' , 'A'
 )
SELECT 
  CAST(C.DATE AS DATETIME)X_DATE,C.ITEM,Q.CLOSEST
  FROM CTE AS C
  OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(X.DATE AS DATETIME)CLOSEST
    FROM CTE AS X
      WHERE X.ITEM='A'AND CAST(X.DATE AS DATETIME)<CAST(C.DATE AS DATETIME)
       ORDER BY CAST(X.DATE AS DATETIME) ASC
 )Q
 WHERE C.ITEM='B'
```

You can use OUTER APPLY-approach as in the above query.
Please also take a look that datetime-column (DATE)is written in the ISO-compliant form

Answer (score 0):

Your data has only two columns.  If you want the only the closest A timestamp, then the fastest way is probably window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when prev_a_date is null then next_a_date
             when next_a_date is null then prev_a_date
             when datediff(second, prev_a_date, date) <= datediff(second, date, next_a_date) then prev_a_date
             else next_a_date
        end) as a_date
from (select t.*,
             max(case when item = 'A' then date end) over (order by date) as prev_a_date,
             min(case when item = 'A' then date end) over (order by date desc) as next_a_date
      from t
     ) t
where item = 'B';
```

This uses seconds to measure the time difference, but you can use a smaller unit if appropriate.

You can also do this using `apply` if you have more columns from the "A" rows that you want:

```
select tb.*, ta.*
from t b outer apply
     (select top (1) ta.*
      from t ta
      where item = 'A'
      order by abs(datediff(second, a.date, b.date))
     ) t
where item = 'B';
```